# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/www/html/project/.next/BUILD_ID'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, npm, next.js

I try to start nextjs projcet, but I have an error like this:

`[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/www/html/project/.next/BUILD_ID'] { errno: -2, code: 'ENOENT', syscall: 'open', path: '/var/www/html/project/.next/BUILD_ID' }`

- It works well locally, but I have this problem on my server.
- The version of node has been changed but it didn't help.
- I ran by sudo but it was useless.

If anyone has information, please help.

Thank you.